# nbconvert into PDF fails to process exclamation mark in Latex

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, latex, nbconvert

If I convert a cell into Markdown and type Latex expression `$ \frac{1}{n!}$` there, then conversion to PDF fails (`jupyter nbconvert --to pdf <filename>.ipynb`).

I reported the bug here https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/6189
but I'm looking for a quick workaround.

I need to type the exclamation mark in a fraction expression, and then convert the notebook into a PDF. How could I workaround this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to workaround this by using `align*` environment instead of `$`, like this:

```
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n!}
\end{align*}
```

Also it helped me troubleshoot it to export first to tex:
`jupyter nbconvert --to latex <filename>.ipynb`, then play with the exported tex file and try to compile it (`xelatex <filename>.tex`)